# return value of one column following index of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
name country gender
john  us      1
john  ca      1
john  sa      0
lisa  sa      1
lisa  da      1
lisa  us      0
wang  da      1
wang  sa      1
wang  da      0
```

for same name, I want all the gender value to be the gender value of country US. For example, we have three johns, I want to change all the gender of john to 1 (which is the gender under us)

the returned frame is

```
john  us  1
john  ca  1
john  sa  1
lisa  sa  0
lisa  da  0
lisa  us  0
wang  da  1
wang  sa  1
wang  da  0
```

I used groupby.transform(), but the code after transform does not work. anyone knows how to solve these kind of problems using pandas

Comment: Please provide your code and error message if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do `groupby.transform` after masking the country not us with `where` and `fillna` with the original values if no us in the name.

```
df['gender'] = (df['gender'].where(df['country'].eq('us'))
                            .groupby(df['name']).transform('first')
                            .fillna(df['gender']).astype(int)
               )
print(df)
   name country  gender
0  john      us       1
1  john      ca       1
2  john      sa       1
3  lisa      sa       0
4  lisa      da       0
5  lisa      us       0
6  wang      da       1
7  wang      sa       1
8  wang      da       0
```

Comment: could you explain transform('first')?

Comment: This is a sample data, for the real data, not all 'us' is the first row in the name. Some us is mixed in the middle of same name. In this case, I'm not sure if transform 'first' would work?

Comment: @codelearner0504 for the name `lisa`, `us` is not the first entry

Comment: @codelearner0504 the `first` in the `groupby` will take the first non Nan value in the group, so even if the `us` is not the first in the group, then it will grab the associated value

Answer (score 2):

Some logic with filter then `update`

```
s=df.loc[df.country=='us'].set_index('name').reindex(df.name)
s.index=df.index
df.update(s[['gender']])
df
Out[65]: 
   name country  gender
0  john      us     1.0
1  john      ca     1.0
2  john      sa     1.0
3  lisa      sa     0.0
4  lisa      da     0.0
5  lisa      us     0.0
6  wang      da     1.0
7  wang      sa     1.0
8  wang      da     0.0
```